# Reading multiple value types from input to produce a linked list in c

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I need to create a linked list based on info put in by the user. The user will put all info in at once and will contain a command and potentially be followed by a string to be loaded to the list or an int value (to reference nodes). ie input: ins monkey  OR prv 1 8  (In these cases the first 3 characters are the command 1st requires an insert of 'monkey' the 2nd would require the printing of nodes with a value between 1 and 8)

I have been working on this for weeks and cannot figure out how to have my program process the second part of the input. I store all the input into an array and then parse it into various arrays depending on the string values but I can't even figure out how to set the struct value for the string to the string that was put in after the command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//self referring struct (keystone to LL)
struct Node
{
    char symbol [11];// each Node contains a array 'symbol'
    int count; // each Node contains a symbol counter
    struct Node *next; // points to the next node (this is the self referential aspect)
    };// end struct







int main()
{
    //function prototypes to be used by main
    void insert(struct Node**, struct Node **,char y[]);
    //char delSym(NodePtr *xPtr, char y[]);
    //char forceDel(NodePtr *xPtr, int z);
    void printList(struct Node*);

    struct Node *head, *tail;
     head = tail= NULL;

    //Declare variables needed for input and output
    char input[15];
    char cmd [4];
    char info [11];
    char str [11];
    char *x= info;
    int val=0;

    //possible command strings
    char ins[4]={'i','n','s'};
    char del[4]={'d','e','l'};
    char fde[4]={'f','d','e'};
    char pst[4]={'p','s','t'};
    char prl[4]={'p','r','l'};
    char pcr[4]={'p','c','r'};
    char ppr[4]={'p','p','r'};
    char psu[4]={'p','s','u'};
    char end[4]={'e','n','d'};


    // Prompt user for command and corresponding input
    puts("Please enter a command with corresponding value(s) where necessary");
    fgets(input,15, stdin);

    //Read the command
    memcpy(cmd, &input[0], 4 );// I am getting the command twice followed by the info????
    memcpy(info, &input[4], 11 );

    printf("%s\n", cmd);// put in to check memcpy
    printf("%s\n", info);



//While command is not 'end':
    while (memcmp(end,cmd,3) != 0)
    {
         // Read value(s) for the command, in necessary
         if (memcmp(ins,cmd, 3)==0)
         {
             insert(&head, &tail, info);
         }


.....


    void insert(struct Node **h, struct Node **t, char y[])
{
   struct Node *temp; // New node
   struct Node *previous; // Previous node
   struct Node *nodePtr; // To walk the LL

    //Allocates a new node and store the appropriate data
    if((temp =(struct Node *)maaloc(sizeof(struct Node)))==NULL)
        {
            printf("Node allocation failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    temp->symbol = y;
    temp->count = count++;



    if(!*h)// If the list is empty make newNode the first node
    {
        *h = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
    else// Insert node if list is not empty
    {
        nodePtr = *h;

        previousNode = NULL;

        while(nodePtr !=NULL)
            {

            if(memcmp(nodePtr->symbol, temp->y, 11)!=0)
            {


                while(nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->count < temp->count)
                    {
                        previousNode = nodePtr;
                        nodePtr = nodePtr ->next;
                    }
                if (previousNode == NULL)
                {
                    *h = temp;
                    temp->next = nodePtr;

                }
                else
                {
                    previousNode->next  = temp;
                    temp->next = nodePtr;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nodePtr->count=count++;
            }
            nodePtr= nodePtr->next;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The particular problem that you describe can be traced to this line:

```
memcpy(cmd, &input[0], 4 );
```

This code copies the first 4 characters of input into `cmd[]`. Presumably the fourth character is a space, so `cmd` is not a string, i.e., `cmd` is not a null-terminated character array. Thus, `printf("%s\n", cmd)` is undefined behavior, likely printing characters until a `0` is encountered somewhere past the end of `cmd`.

You could change the offending line so that it only copies three characters from input:

```
memcpy(cmd, &input[0], 3);
```

Note that `cmd` is still not a string, as the final element has not been initialized to `\0` yet. You could now do `cmd[3] = '\0'`. It may be better to initialize `cmd` at the point of declaration:

```
char cmd[4] = {0};
```

Note also that `fgets()` keeps the newline (so long as the input buffer is large enough), so `info` will likely contain a `\n` before the `\0` that you may wish to remove.

None of the "possible command strings" are actually strings, they are character arrays, and only the first three bytes have been initialized in each of them.

One fix would be to add null terminators:

```
char ins[4]={'i', 'n', 's', '\0'};
```

It would be better to initialize from a string literal, and let the compiler determine the sizes of the arrays:

```
char ins[] = "ins";
```